# Pass deep prop to shallow input

Tags: graphql

If I have a query `user` and it takes `uuid` but my variables are deep `user.uuid` can I pass `uuid` to the `user` query?

```
query User($user.uuid: string) {
  user (uuid:$user.uuid) {
    createdAt
  }
}
```

Query Variables:

```
{
  "user":{
    "uuid": "abc"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/248

Answer (score 0):

No, the current GraphQL spec does not support referencing properties of a variable if that variable is an object. You may pass in object variables, but they may only be used where an input object is expected, for example, given a schema like:

```
type Mutation {
  createUser(input: UserInput!): User!
}

input UserInput {
  email: String!
}
```

we can do

```
mutation ($input: UserInput!) {
  createUser(input: $input) {
    email
  }
}
```

However, if the expected input is a scalar:

```
type Mutation {
  createUser(email: String!): User!
}
```

we must provide the scalar as a separate variable:

```
mutation ($email: String!) {
  createUser(email: $email) {
    email
  }
}
```